Problems with centering a Material UI modal
I am new using Material UI and Tailwind, so I have a question, why the LfProjectModal component does not appear in the center of the screen but it appears in the upper left corner? I am using the LfProjectModal component in this other component:
return (
    <div className="mx-4">
      <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row md:justify-between">
        <div className="flex justify-center md:justify-start">
          <LfArchiveButton redirectUrl="/dashboard/archived-projects" />
          <LfClockButton />
          <LfReloadButton handleReload={fetchProjects} />
          <LfAddButton onClick={handleOpenModal} />
          {isModalOpen && (
            <LfProjectModal
              open={isModalOpen}
              handleClose={handleCloseModal}
              fetchProjects={fetchProjects}
            />
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="my-3 text-center md:my-6 md:mr-7 md:text-right">
          <h1 className="font-semibold text-blue-500">
            Proyectos ({projects.length})
          </h1>
          <p>{currentDate}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className=" w-full">
        {!loading ? (
          sortProjectsByState(projects).map((project) => (
            <LfPanel
              key={project.project_uid}
              panelKey={project.project_uid}
              panelName={project.project_name}
              panelFreelancer={project.project_users}
              panelState={project.project_state}
              panelLink="projects/tasks/"
              panelImage={project.user_picture}
              panelIsProject={true}
              fetchProjects={fetchProjects}
            />
          ))
        ) : (
          <div className="flex w-full items-center justify-center">
            <Loader />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )

And this is my component LfProjectModal:
return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <div className="m-4 max-h-min max-w-md rounded-2xl border-2 border-white-500 bg-black-500 p-8">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit, onError)}>
            <Stack spacing={2}>
              <div className="mt-4">
                <LfInput
                  label="Nombre del proyecto"
                  name="project_name"
                  register={register}
                  obligatory
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <LfSelectInput
                  label="Tipo de proyecto"
                  name="project_type_uid"
                  register={register}
                  options={options}
                  obligatory
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <LfMultiSelectInput
                  label="Participantes"
                  name="user_uid"
                  control={control}
                  options={freelancers}
                  obligatory
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <LfDatePicker
                  label="Fecha de inicio"
                  name="project_start_date"
                  control={control}
                  obligatory
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <LfDatePicker
                  label="Fecha de entrega"
                  name="project_deadline"
                  control={control}
                  obligatory
                />
              </div>
            </Stack>
            <div className="mt-4 flex content-center justify-center">
              <LfButton>Crear Proyecto</LfButton>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  )

I am also attaching an image of how the modal is currently appearing to me:

As you can see, the modal is in a div that is located before the , this image shows the position of the component in the HTML and its css.

I've tried to eliminate the m-4 max-h-min max-w-md of my modal's css but it didn't works. That's what happen when I do that:

Thanks to everyone who can help me!

Modal, by default, is designed to open in the center as per the component showcase page it looks like. Can you inspect your modal and see what styles are being applied?

Your modal by default is positioned absolute, and if you nested your modal inside an element with position relative, then it would be positioned relative to that container and not to the browser window like you want. I would always recommend to never nest modals in other elements, instead every modal should be placed before the closing </body> tag so that it can always be positioned relative to the browser window instead of some other element.

@RahulMehta None that I think affect the position of the Modal, it's just padding styles, font color, background color, borders and that's it.

@zgood how can I do that? I'm making my web application with Next.js, so there are many components and many are called inside other components

what @zgood suggested, is the default behavior of MUI modal even if you set it inside a div (See react or mui portal). Can you verify this by inspect element and see that the modal does infact open directly under the body tag?

@ValentinaLoaiza Since I am just guessing that this might be a problem, I would first inspect the modal in the browser when its open and see if in fact there are other 's or other elements wrapping the modal container and see if setting all wrapping elements to position static fixes the problem. The problem could be something else, I am not sure

@RahulMehta Checking I realized that the modal is inside a div (which occupies the entire screen) and indeed that div by default is located just before closing the  tag as you can see in the image I left in the question

@zgood The divs in which the modal is located have a fixed position

@ValentinaLoaiza Ya your nesting looks fine, so it doesn't seem like that is the issue. Try removing these 3 classes -> m-4 max-h-min max-w-md from your modal component and see if that fixes the issue

@zgood No, I had already tried that and it doesn't work either, in the question I left an image of what happens when I remove that part of the css.

So, for starters, you wouldn't need the Modal to sit inside a div in the LfProjectModal file. You can remove the div tag. Next, I think only the m-4 is messing with the modal's position. Worst case maybe just try setting the default modal CSS properties like position, top, left and that should work
